# How can I add dynamic created elements to my dynamic created list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I'm having some issues adding dynamic created list items to dynamic created list. I've created a function that returns dynamically created `ul` and `li`.

From here I create two lists:

```
var el          = Part.mainSearchResult();
var brandList   = $(el.ul).clone(true);
var storeList   = $(el.ul).clone(true);
```

Q1. Should I use `.clone()` here?

Then I try to add the list elements to the list, and output this. But I'm not that successfullt.

Q2. What am I doing wrong when applying list elements to list?

[You can see my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/etsg4vvw/2/)

```
var Part = {
    mainSearchResult : function(){
        var el = {}
        el.ul = $("<ul />", {
            'data-role': "listview",
            'data-inset' : "true"
        });

        el.brand = $("<li />", { 'data-role': "listview", 'data-inset' : "true"})
            .append($("<a />", { 'href': "#"}));

        el.store = $('<li/>', {'data-role': "listview", 'data-inset' : "true"}).append(
            $('<a/>', {'href': '#'}).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': "name"})
            ).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': "location"})
            )
        );
        return el;
    }
};

function test(response) {
    var el          = Part.mainSearchResult();
    var brandList   = $(el.ul).clone(true);
    var storeList   = $(el.ul).clone(true);

    $(response.brands).each(function(){
        var brand = $(this)[0];    
        var url = 'http://www.jsfiddle.com/' + brand.name + '/' + brand.id;
        var li = el.brand[0];  // Maybe I should clone this?
        $(li).find('a').prop('href',url);
        $(li).find('a').text(brand.name);
        brandList.append(li);
    });

    $('.result').append(brandList);    
    console.log(brandList);
}
```

Comment: it works...http://jsfiddle.net/etsg4vvw/3/ ...or is that not what its supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the html in the css pane :D

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etsg4vvw/4/